Azure computer vision api
I attempted to extract text from the receiving emails' inline images. The number of inline images could be n. It indicates that the file is in an incorrect format when I attempt to extract it using the Azure Computer Vision API. For processing, the image should be 50 by 50 pixels. How can we get over this? Is there a way to resolve this

[mre] required.

preprocess the image and resize it to 50x50 pixels.

According to this documentation the supported formats are
JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP, WEBP, ICO, TIFF, or MPO
and the minimum dimensions is 50 x 50 pixels, so preprocess your image so that it met the above conditions.
Below is the sample preprocessing function using PIL library.
from PIL import Image

def preprocess_image(image_path):
    with Image.open(image_path) as img:
        if img.size[0] < 50 or img.size[1] < 50:
            img = img.resize((50, 50))
        img = img.convert("RGB") 
        img.save(image_path)

I am just resizing here, you do according to your requirements.

Thank you Jayashanker , I tried resizing the image but the quality of image becomes very poor so that vision api is not able to recognise the texts properly.The images I am working with is a bit small. Is there any other optimal solution for this
